# My kendo grid column filter icon popup is not displaying properly

Tags: kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and its have filterable "true", when click on filter icon,it displays like below.When we enter the text in filter box,half of the letters are displayed only.Is it possible to increment the size of text-boxes in filter?
What is problem here?And how to resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try to increase the text box height

Once try this

```
  .k-numeric-wrap .k-input
{
 height:23px
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your css styling might be conflicting with kendo's css styling. If you are using chrome, right click on the textbox and click Inspect Element. (I am sure you can also inspect elements in other browsers as well. In IE press F12.)

Have a look at the styling on the element or sometimes the styling of the parent element also cause issues?