# How to increase the size of text box in filter menu

Tags: css, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid in my application, in grid filterable is true.Filtering is working fine.When click on filter symbol,opened the filter menu. I want to increase the size of that text-box in filter menu.Because when we entered the values in text-box,it displays only half size of letters.I tried this as

```
.k-filtermenu .k-textbox {
    min-height:10000px
 }
```

How to increase that text-box size? If any one know about this please reply me....

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/390/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you out;

```
.k-numeric-wrap .k-input
{
 height:23px
 }
```

try this also:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/how-to-change-the-width-of-the-edit-textbox-when-grideditmode-inline.aspx

Comment: thank you for quick reply my problem is in this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472235/my-kendo-grid-column-filter-icon-popup-is-not-displaying-properly once check it please.

Comment: hi this is the my requirement can any one help me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472235/my-kendo-grid-column-filter-icon-popup-is-not-displaying-properly